# Force USB Thumb Drive to Mount Before Continue

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I am writing an updater program on in C# using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7. I would like the user to insert a USB thumb drive and if the program finds the drive and updates on the drive then it automatically copies them over. I desire to check only once at startup and then execute a program that is unaware of the updates (updates really need to happen with the program shutdown).

My issue is that the update program is being run before the thumb drive is being mounted so the computer detects no thumb drive and no updates and moves on prematurely. I want to have everything running as fast as possible but I need to force any thumb drives to mount before detection. Everything must be automatic with no input from the user.

Is this possible in c#?

Edit with more detail:

I currently run a batch file at startup (actually as the Windows 7 shell, but I'm not sure that makes a difference). The batch file runs the update check then the actual program. If the user had the USB drive stuck in at boot then I would like the updater to look at the drive and copy over any new files.

The current coded looks like:

```
 DriveInfo[] ListDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
 foreach (DriveInfo Drive in ListDrives)
 {
      if(Drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
      {
           // double check it's valid and copy over stuff
      }
 }
```

but it currently finds no drives at boot. If I run it later then everything is fine. I am assuming that since I run the updater so early it just hasn't had a chance to mount, but I don't just want to wait N seconds if I don't have to because under normal circumstances that's just dead time.

If I can do this check easy up from it is much simpler than having to continually monitor for an event and then shut everything down and do an update.

Comment: I feel like you have omitted some details necessary to understand what problem you are attempting to solve. When does your program run? Where does it run from? How does it know which drive is a usb drive?  Because you chose to only perform the update check one time on startup in the background....then how do you notify the user that they should insert the drive at the appropriate time so you do not have a race condition with reality?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Thanks, I added a bit more info in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a solution like the following one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

/// <summary>
/// Represents our program class which contains the entry point of our application.
/// </summary>
public class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the entry point of our application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Possibly spcified command line arguments.</param>
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RemovableDriveWatcher rdw = new RemovableDriveWatcher();   // Create a new instance of the RemoveableDriveWatcher class.
        rdw.NewDriveFound += NewDriveFound;                        // Connect to the "NewDriveFound" event.
        rdw.DriveRemoved += DriveRemoved;                          // Connect to the "DriveRemoved" event.
        rdw.Start();                                               // Start watching.

        // Do something here...
        Console.ReadLine();

        rdw.Stop();                                                // Stop watching.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is executed when a new drive has been found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender of this event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The event arguments containing the changed drive.</param>
    private static void NewDriveFound(object sender, RemovableDriveWatcherEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Found a new drive, the name is: {0}", e.ChangedDrive.Name));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is executed when a drive has been removed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender of this event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The event arguments containing the changed drive.</param>
    private static void DriveRemoved(object sender, RemovableDriveWatcherEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The drive with the name {0} has been removed.", e.ChangedDrive.Name));
    }
}
```

The RemoveableDriveWatcher class looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Repesents a watcher class for removable drives.
/// </summary>
public class RemovableDriveWatcher
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the watcher thread which watches for new drives.
    /// </summary>
    private Thread watcherThread;

    /// <summary>
    /// Continas all found logical drives of this system.
    /// </summary>
    private List<DriveInfo> foundDrives;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RemovableDriveWatcher"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public RemovableDriveWatcher()
    {
        this.foundDrives = new List<DriveInfo>();
        this.watcherThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ScanLogicalDrives));
        this.WaitBetweenScansDelay = 1000;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is fired if a new drive has been detected.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<RemovableDriveWatcherEventArgs> NewDriveFound;

    /// <summary>
    /// Is fired if a drive has been removed.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<RemovableDriveWatcherEventArgs> DriveRemoved;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the delay in ms between two scans.
    /// </summary>
    public int WaitBetweenScansDelay
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the watcher.
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        if (!this.watcherThread.IsAlive)
        {
            this.watcherThread.Start();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the watcher.
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        if (this.watcherThread.IsAlive)
        {
            this.watcherThread.Abort();
            this.watcherThread.Join();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Scans for logical drives and fires an event every time a new
    /// drive has been found or a drive was removed.
    /// </summary>
    private void ScanLogicalDrives()
    {
        DriveInfo[] drives;

        do
        {
            drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            // Check for new drives
            foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
            {
                if (!(drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (!drive.IsReady)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (!this.foundDrives.ContainsWithName(drive))
                {
                    this.foundDrives.Add(drive);

                    if (this.NewDriveFound != null)
                    {
                        this.NewDriveFound(this, new RemovableDriveWatcherEventArgs(drives, drive));
                    }
                }
            }

            // Check for removed drives
            for (int i = this.foundDrives.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                DriveInfo drive = this.foundDrives[i];
                if (!drives.ContainsWithName(drive))
                {
                    if (this.DriveRemoved != null)
                    {
                        this.DriveRemoved(this, new RemovableDriveWatcherEventArgs(drives, drive));
                    }

                    this.foundDrives.RemoveWithName(drive);
                }
            }

            // Sleep
            Thread.Sleep(this.WaitBetweenScansDelay);
        }
        while (true);
    }
}
```

For everything to work you need the RemovableDriveWatcherEventArgs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the RemovableDriveWatcherEventArgs
/// </summary>
public class RemovableDriveWatcherEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RemovableDriveWatcherEventArgs"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="allDrives">All currently available logical drives in the system.</param>
    /// <param name="changedDrive">The changed drive.</param>
    public RemovableDriveWatcherEventArgs(DriveInfo[] allDrives, DriveInfo changedDrive)
    {
        this.Drives = allDrives;
        this.ChangedDrive = changedDrive;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the changed logical drive that has either been detected or removed.
    /// </summary>
    public DriveInfo ChangedDrive { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all currently available logical drives.
    /// </summary>
    public DriveInfo[] Drives { get; private set; }
}
```

And of course the Extensions:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains extensions used by the RemovableDriveWatcher class.
/// </summary>
public static class RemovableDriveWatcherExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extends the DiveInfo[] by the ContainsWithName method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="all">The array where we want to find the specified instance.</param>
    /// <param name="search">The instance which we want to find in the array.</param>
    /// <returns>TRUE if the specified instance was found, FALSE if the specified instance was not found.</returns>
    public static bool ContainsWithName(this DriveInfo[] all, DriveInfo search)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < all.Length; i++)
        {
            if (all[i].Name == search.Name)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extends the List<DriveInfo> by the ContainsWithName method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="all">The array where we want to find the specified instance.</param>
    /// <param name="search">The instance which we want to find in the list.</param>
    /// <returns>TRUE if the specified instance was found, FALSE if the specified instance was not found.</returns>
    public static bool ContainsWithName(this List<DriveInfo> all, DriveInfo search)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < all.Count; i++)
        {
            if (all[i].Name == search.Name)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extends the List<DriveInfo> by the RemoveWithName method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="all">The array where we want to removed the specified instance.</param>
    /// <param name="search">The instance which we want to remove in the list.</param>
    public static void RemoveWithName(this List<DriveInfo> all, DriveInfo search)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < all.Count; i++)
        {
            if (all[i].Name == search.Name)
            {
                all.RemoveAt(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much detail, but it seems likely you could call DriveInfo.GetDrives() which returns an array of type DriveInfo[]

DriveInfo has an IsReady() method. Presumably once you check that the drive is ready, you can look for a well-known file on the USB drive() to verify they have mounted the correct USB

You could poll in a loop till you find what you want, but if you don't find what you want in say 60 seconds, you will need to notify the user that you can't find the USB drive you need.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a ready check inside of the if statement.  According to MSDN:

> IsReady indicates whether a drive is ready. For example, it indicates
>   whether a CD is in a CD drive or **whether a removable storage device is** 
>   ready for read/write operations. If you do not test whether a drive is
>   ready, and it is not ready, querying the drive using DriveInfo will
>   raise an IOException.

Are you checking for an IOException?  I do not see an [IsReady](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.isready.aspx) event so you may have to spinwait or hook into the lower level Windows API to find an event to indicate drive readiness.  Here's an idea for the meantime:

```
try
{
    DriveInfo[] ListDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
     foreach (DriveInfo Drive in ListDrives)
     {
          if(!Drive.IsReady)//spin

          if(Drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
          {
               // double check it's valid and copy over stuff
          }
     }
}
catch(IOException ex)//...
```

I don't have any way to test this right now.  Please let me know how it works out for you or if there's more details I need to be aware of.

However, because you are starting this process on startup there's always the possibility that `IsReady` will not be sufficient and once again you may have to find something else (Windows API I imagine).  I have not discovered any documentation that say's anything to the effect.