# Programmatically getting time required for complete system boot up?

Tags: c, windows, boot

I have written an application for defragmenation which starts at boot time.We know every system boots up faster or slower depending on its configuration.I have given hard coded value of 3 seconds during boot time so that,windows registers all ports during that time.I just want to know,are there any APIs existing which gives exact time when windows system is completely ready at boot time.That is whether all USB ports and others got recognized or not.?

Comment: I understand what you're asking, but you should instead ask a more specific question. What *exactly* do you want to wait for? All possible external drives to become mounted?  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691803 (although I certainly hope you aren't considering defrag-ing any flash storage devices!)

Comment: Actually, what i want is how much time does windows system takes to register USB keyboard and hence,recognizes key presses.

Comment: Immediately. Windows recognizes keypresses at the log-in screen.

Comment: Yes,obviously.But,i want keypress at boot time on that black screen.Similar to that windows check disk screen,where message appears like "Press any key to abort windows check disk".

Comment: You want your application to get keypresses before the OS has even started loading? What are you actually developing?

Comment: I am developing a Boot time 'Defragmenter'. The main crux is to get keyboard response for following message "Press ESC key to abort or Press any other to continue".

Comment: And how are you launching this application? No matter the method, I would think the keyboard would be ready by that point, rendering this "wait" unnecessary.

Comment: I am launching this application at boot time.But,at boot time USB keyboard does not get recognized and hence i have added "wait".so that, it gets recognized.For PS2 keyboard there is no need to add "wait",because motherboard has port on itself for PS2 keyboards and hence easily recognizes PS2 keyboard at boot time.But,problem persists for USB keyboard.There is no other way,you need to add some "wait".

Comment: Enable "Legacy USB" in your BIOS. Your USB keyboard should work even as early as entering your BIOS setup / selecting boot devices, all the way through real mode, text mode boot, and into Windows. All long before your application ever comes alive.

Comment: I have already tried it and even though problem was persisting so, i had added "wait".

Comment: I don't know the answer, but one way out might be to use some sort of [Windows Kernel Debugger](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=94) and another way out may be to code and troubleshoot your tool against an open source Windows-compatible OS where you can study all kernel aspects freely: https://www.reactos.org/wiki/Supported_USB_Devices

Comment: Is there any **NT API** which will give me time regarding system is ready or not.?